# Auto-generated Webservice call fails with unmarshalling error?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws, cxf

I'm trying to create a test client fro a public webservice:
http://www.webservicex.com/currencyconvertor.asmx?WSDL

Used Eclipse with CXF 2.x to auto-generate the WS Client. Which looks fine so far, but on execution I only get the following error.
I occures wehn I call the webservice method `conversionRate`, which is also auto-generated as follows:

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/", name = "CurrencyConvertorSoap")
@XmlSeeAlso({ObjectFactory.class})
public interface CurrencyConvertorSoap {

    @WebResult(name = "ConversionRateResult", targetNamespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "ConversionRate", targetNamespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/", className = "ConversionRate")
    @WebMethod(operationName = "ConversionRate", action = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "ConversionRateResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/", className = "ConversionRateResponse")
    public double conversionRate(
        @WebParam(name = "FromCurrency", targetNamespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/")
        Currency fromCurrency,
        @WebParam(name = "ToCurrency", targetNamespace = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/")
        Currency toCurrency
    );
}
```

How can I find out where the error comes from? What might be wrong here?

Error:

```
Warnung: Interceptor for {http://www.webserviceX.NET/}CurrencyConvertor#{http://www.webserviceX.NET/}ConversionRate has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: unerwartetes Element (URI:"http://www.webserviceX.NET/", lokal:"ConversionRateResult"). Erwartete Elemente sind <{}ConversionRateResult> 
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:808)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:629)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:157)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:103)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:800)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1592)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1490)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1309)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:622)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:271)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:463)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:366)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:319)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:133)
    at $Proxy35.conversionRate(Unknown Source)
    at CurrencyConvertorSoap_CurrencyConvertorSoap_Client.main(CurrencyConvertorSoap_CurrencyConvertorSoap_Client.java:50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to NOT delete the auto-generated `package-info.java`.
In general, when creating normal Java projects, this artifact can be removed savely. But in case of webservices it contains mandatory definitions.

Comment: Or when you call the wsdl2java, pass an -xjc-npa flag which would tell JAXB's XJC to not use the package-info and instead generate a lot more information in the annotations.

Comment: I just encountered a similar problem, where I get a "not valid value" Unmarshalling Error but without any hint about the element in question, except for the "offending value". Since I have hundreds of elements in the XML message, it's like searching a needle in a haystack. My workaround for this stage is to provide unique (bogus) values for each element and since values (but not elements) are reported, it points me to the right element. It's tedious and not very smart, though. I will try the `-xjc-npa` flag once I am going to re-build. Thanks +1.